# Use standard LaTeX font in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

How do I change the font in beamer to be as the standard font in a normal LaTeX document?

As far as I have found, the standard font in LaTeX is `computer modern roman`, but I don't know how to set the font to this.

Comment: Think hard before you do this. The text might not be as readable at a distance in an auditorium, cm is a rather "thin" or "light" font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\frac{b}{c} ABC a\cdot n\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```